# wp options page color picker val not saved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've setup na options page for a wordpress plugin. In the form I'm using a field with the wp color picker. Everything works fine an the picker does show up in that form but on submit the value of the Picker isn't saved:

Here is the code from the plugin file:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'findMeSpot_enqueue_color_picker' );
function findMeSpot_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {
    // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', plugins_url('inc/my-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'findmespot_add_options_page');

function findmespot_add_options_page(){
    add_options_page('FindMeSpot Settings', 'FindMeSpot', 'manage_options', 'findmespot', 'findMeSpot_options_page');
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_findMeSpot_settings' );
}

function findMeSpot_options_page(){
    require 'inc/options_page.php';
}
function register_findMeSpot_settings(){
        register_setting('findMeSpot_display_settings_group', 'findMeSpot_display_settings');

}
```

and here the form:

```
    <?php echo var_dump(get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings'))?>

<br class="clear" />
<p><strong>Settings to display the map in the frontend</strong></p>
<table class="widefat">
    <thead>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'findMeSpot_display_settings_group' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'findMeSpot_display_settings_group' ); ?>
    <tr>
        <th class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Setting:', 'wp_admin_style' ); ?></th>
        <th><?php esc_attr_e( 'Options:', 'wp_admin_style' ); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="row-title"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e(
                    'Feed ID:', 'wp_admin_style'
                        ); ?></label></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings')['ID'] ?>" size="60" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[ID]"/><p class="description">Enter the ID of your public feed from findmespot.com. You find this ID, when you open your feed in the URL:
                            http://share.findmespot.com/shared/faces/viewspots.jsp?glId=<code>0XapxKiqW4RCHYhVkaCBpaHT3cNMUcEef</code></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternate">
        <td class="row-title"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e(
                    'Map width:', 'wp_admin_style'
                ); ?> </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings')['mapWidth'] ?>" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[mapWidth]" id="map_width" /><p class="description"> Enter the width of the map. 500px by default.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Map height:', 'wp_admin_style' ); ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings')['mapHeight'] ?>" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[mapHeight]" id="map_width" /><p class="description"> Enter the height of the map. 500px by default.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternate">
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Map type:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>
                        <td><select name="findMeSpot_display_settings[mapType]">
                                <option  value="ROADMAP">ROADMAP</option>   
                                <option  value="TERRAIN">TERRAIN</option>   
                                <option  value="SATELITE">SATELITE</option>   
                                <option  value="HYBRIDE">HYBRIDE</option>   
                            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Show legend:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[showLegend]" checked="true"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="alternate">
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Legend height:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings')['legendHeight'] ?>" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[legendHeight]" width="3"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Auto refresh:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings')['autoRefresh'] ?>" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[autoRefresh]" width="3"><p class="description">The auto refresh interval for the track data. By default 5 minutes. You should not use less than 3 minutes because it is possible that requests can be blocked if you hit the server in an higher frequence.</p></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="alternate">
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Polyline:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>
                <td></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Stroke color:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[strokeColor]" value="<?php echo get_option('findMeSpot_display_settings')['strokeColor'] ?>" 
                           class="my-color-field"  data-default-color="#effeff"  />
                    <p class="description">The color of the line on the map that connects your waypoints.</p></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="alternate">
        <td class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e(
                'Stroke weight:', 'wp_admin_style'
            ); ?></td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="findMeSpot_display_settings[strokeWeight]" value="3" /><p class="descritpion">The weight of the line that connects your waypoints on the map. 3px by default.</p></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="alternate">
            <td class="row-title"><input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="Example" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'save changes' ); ?>" /></td>
                <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th class="row-title"><?php esc_attr_e( 'findMeSpot-Plugin', 'wp_admin_style' ); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo( '&copy; ' .  date(Y) . ' By <a href="http://www.poppgerhard.at">Popp Gerhard</a> if you need help, <a href="mailto:office@sewemo.eu"> mail me here.</a>'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
        </form>
</table>
```

and the enqueued script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker();
});
```

As you can see im only using the wp standard color picker and a array of settings. And i`ve no idea why the value of the picker does not append to the posts array.

Anyone a suggestion how to debug that?

Thanks and nice greets from vienna.
regards Howard

Comment: Do you have any errors on page? Turn on the debugging in your wordpress when developing theme/plugins - go to wp-config.php and find and set debug to true: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: Debuging is on as well ass E_ALL. I also console log the val of the input field and on change it is set but it isnt in the post array on submit.

Comment: Update: if i use the iris color picker instead everything works well.